# How to set up embedded projects for maintainability

Tags: version-control, configuration, project-structure

We are about to start using FreeRTOS with lwip and mbed-tls as a platform for new products.
We're working in an Linux environment and I'm tasked with setting up our first project.

In Linux we typically have the platform (distribution) as a repository and then repos for all our applications.

With the RTOS I'm not sure that is the best solution. It would basically mean that the project would depend on the RTOS as a library but since we are preparing for multiple products on the same platform, the RTOS config might not be the same for each product which would mean that the RTOS library would have to be rebuilt for each product.

Having a local copy of the RTOS sources in each product would solve this but would instead make upgrades and bug-fixes harder.

Are there any good ways of solving this?

We're using git repos and Makefiles for our Linux products.